How to parse HTML format in google docs via apps script?
Any way we can render html formatting in google docs via apps script?
For example,
I am getting an Input "<p> <b>Hello</b> <i>world</i> </p>"
(parsed as "Hello world")
Any library available that parses the above text and appropriately adds the text to the document and sets the formatting as such?
EDIT: DUPLICATE: Inject HTML into Google Docs using Google Apps Script
